# javascript countdown timer goes negative

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

I'm trying to implement a countdown timer on my mobile site using javascript. I've got this but the timer goes into negative, it doesn't stop. I want it to stop at 0:0.

**JavaScript**

```
// set minutes
var mins = 5;

// calculate seconds
var secs = mins * 60;
function countdown() {
setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}
function Decrement() {
if (document.getElementById) {
minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
// if less than a minute remaining
if (seconds < 59) {
seconds.value = secs;
} else {
minutes.value = getminutes();
seconds.value = getseconds();
}
secs--;
setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}
}
function getminutes() {
// minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
return mins;
}
function getseconds() {
// take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="timer">
This is only valid for the next <input id="minutes" type="text" style="width: 14px; border: none; background-color:transparent; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;"> minutes and <input id="seconds" type="text" style="width: 26px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;"> seconds.
</div>
```

And I'm also trying to change the font color countdown minute to red but it doesn't seem to change?

```
<input id="minutes" type="text" style="width: 14px; border: none; background-color:transparent; font-size: 16px; **font-color:red;** font-weight: bold;">
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You are unconditionally setting `setTimeout` to repeat. Try `if( secs > 0) setTimeout(Decrement,1000)`
2. The CSS is `color`, not `font-color`

Your code is a mess too...

```js
var time = 5 * 60,
    start = Date.now(),
    mins = document.getElementById('minutes'),
    secs = document.getElementById('seconds'),
    timer;

function countdown() {
  var timeleft = Math.max(0, time - (Date.now() - start) / 1000),
      m = Math.floor(timeleft / 60),
      s = Math.floor(timeleft % 60);
  
  mins.firstChild.nodeValue = m;
  secs.firstChild.nodeValue = s;
  
  if( timeleft == 0) clearInterval(timer);
}

timer = setInterval(countdown, 200);
```

```html
<div id="timer">
This is only valid for the next <strong id="minutes">-</strong> minutes and <strong id="seconds">-</strong> seconds.
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, how long have we been able to do that inline code snippet thingy? -- [Answered on the blog, natch](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick simple counter you can use for your own sake

```
var mins=5;
var secs = mins*60;
var timerInterv = setInterval(doCountDown, 1000);
var outMins,outSecs
function doCountDown()
{
    --secs;
    if (secs<=0)
    { outMins=outSecs=0;
    clearInterval(timerInterv);
    return;
    }
    outMins = parseInt(secs/60);
    outSecs = secs%60;

    console.log("M:"+outMins+" S:"+outSecs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add check before decrementing secs

```
if (secs > 0) {
        secs--;
        setTimeout('Decrement()', 1000);
    }
```

for font color add color:red in your style that refers on minutes